# Why so many packages?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu

Why does Ubuntu have so many packages compared to Debian?

[image]

Can someone suggest a program that shows unused packages?

Ubuntu/lubuntu is a great distro but check out the debian amount of packages

[image]

Comment: I can think of a few unused packages on my system such as "Thunderbird" but it might be referenced by other programs I do use. A script that shows all programs that haven't been accessed since installation might be a good idea. Not sure if a program exists to do this already.

Comment: See `man apt-cache` to learn how to list package statistics and package lists.

Comment: Some packages depend on others to function, so what seems "unused" may in fact be necessary for a program you frequently use. I wouldn't touch things that have `lib` prefix or anything Python/Perl or has .so extension. Otherwise, if you know what things you remove and why, and nothing depends on it - feel free to do so.  General wisdom : don't fix what ain't broke

Comment: @user535733 i already listed the packages, but has so many libs that i just left in concern to not broke the system

Comment: If you want to install with fewer packages, you might look at doing a [minimal installation](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-18-04-minimal-install-option), or even using the [minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I think you're comparing oranges & lemons, ie. builds for *armv* (raspberry pi or single-board computers) usually are low-resource machines, so packagers purposely keep it light.  To compare I suspect you should be comparing x86_64 with x86_64.

Mostly Ubuntu tries very much to give a '*great out of the box*' experience, this by definition means more packages are needed.

Debian has strict principles (*free as in freedom, not free as in free beer*) thus making even non-free (no cost binaries without source-code) more of a hassle. Ubuntu is not as strict (though still has freedom rules too!)

You can select a box during install, and install codecs in Ubuntu; ie. it provides *non-free* far easier on Ubuntu than Debian, this means you have more packages too by default.

Yes you can add them to debian (some builds do include non-free) & we [*users mostly*] do -- but my point is Ubuntu adds more to give a better out-of-the-box experience...

links that maybe useful:

- what Ubuntu 'main' can include - https://www.ubuntu.com/licensing
- a guide for debian devs using Ubuntu -
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/ForDebianDevelopers

--

*I've been testing Lubuntu 18.10 (x86 or 32bit) lots in this cycle, I've noted `htop`, `vim` & many packages I normally install are already there.  This is an example of 'great-out-the-box' experience, that I'd not expect to see in a debian build*

Additional interesting info:

- @N0rbert provided this site, it tracks package repositories of distros (including some non-GNU/Linux) providing a great wealth of information on the freshness of packages (and including showing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS & 18.10 releases).
  https://repology.org/

  - @wjandrea mentioned in comment (*yep I've stolen it*) that Ubuntu has Minimal installation options to make it 'trim'. There is the minimalCD image (see link) plus an option on install for 18.04 that installs normally, then deletes packages (on a list) reducing the number of installed packages when you boot (note: this option isn't available for all flavors)
    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: I think that you can add good link to your answer - [https://repology.org/](https://repology.org/). They have counted all packages in all repositories. This is not for "Why?" part of the question, but it is a good illustration of number of packages :)